# Trouble returning custom field values from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am integrated a php login system and created some custom fields in the user registration form which populate the database just fine. But I can't seem to return the custom field values from the database--only the fields that were built in like username. I created a field called displayname and want to show that on a page. I know the answer could be dependent on the code, but in general, shouldn't I be able to return any value regardless as long as the session is active and the connection to the database works and retuns the built in field data?

here is the php code on each page (that works for native username)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] !== true) {

if(empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) ||
empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])){

if ( !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {

if ( !isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) {  ...etc.
```

Then I am trying to call my custom field "bio" with:

```
<?php echo "hi ".$_SESSION['username']; ?>
<?php echo "Your Bio ".$_SESSION['bio']; ?>
```

Why will username return the value but not my custom bio field? Again, I know it might depend on the script I am using, but in theory, shouldn't this work? Or is their some general thoughts anyone might have on why it doesn't return custom field values?

Comment: Are you sure you're storing it in a database instead of a user session? Or have you implemented sessions on a DB?

Answer (score 0):

Session doesn't contains every field value. Suppose you are retrieving the bio from database and storing it in $bio. You must also store bio in session using `$_SESSION['bio'] = $bio;` Only then you will be able to use it everywhere until your session is destroyed.

**Edit**
Session Tutorial
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: That makes sense. (This is my first time using sessions). I didn't see the native username being stored like that, but I get it. So I need to store it on the page with the registration form where the user enters the field? What about other variables I create later that are not part of registration? I always need to store them using the code you provided on the same page where they are created in the website?

Comment: You can store anything in Sessions on any page (Php Script). Example: $xyz = function(); you want to store it in sessions, just add it to session $_SESSION['xyz'] = $xyz. You can go through the tutorial first here http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php. And mark it as answer if it helped.